# Packagist.org: what does it mean when a package has a version number like: 4.4.x-dev?

Tags: packagist

When browsing the packagist.org repositories you see packages with these version numbers e.g. If you look at the [Phpunit repo](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit)

There are a few instances

- `4.5.x-dev`
- `4.3.x-dev`
- `4.2.x-dev`

Do these packages contain the current work the developers are performing towards basic updates, security and bugfixes etc on an otherwise basically stable package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the dev branches. These are unstable and contain bug fixes, etc. This will eventually be released as `4.5.8` for instance (if the library is still supported).

You can get it by using `4.5.x-dev` or `4.5.*@dev` as version constraint.